# Сложение вещественных чисел с разными знаками

Tags: float, binary, числа-с-плавающей-точкой, ieee-754

Пытаюсь понять, как происходит сложение вещественных чисел в формате `binary32` (он же `single precision` или просто `float` в большинстве языков программирования), но немного не понимаю, почему ожидаемый результат отличается от реального.

Есть 2 вещественных числа, которые представлены в формате `binary32` стандарта `IEEE754`: `-987.6543` и `1234.5678`. С самим стандартом ознакомлен, поэтому основные принципы понимаю.

Числа имеют разные порядки, поэтому я изначально поднял порядок числа `-987.6543` на одно значение, чтобы порядки обоих операндов были равны. При изменении порядка числа `-987.6543` самый младший бит был отсечён, так как при сдвиге вышел за пределы установленной разрядной сетки, а бит нормализации перешёл в дробную часть мантиссы, таким образом, число утратило свою нормализованную форму (числа предварительно записаны в двоичном формате, и все операции выполняются непосредственно в двоичной системе счисления).

Затем я представил отрицательное число в дополнительном коде и просто сложил между собой мантиссы двух чисел. Вот на этом этапе возникает самый первый и основной вопрос. Первое число осталось нормализованным, а второе утратило оный вид, так как значение бита нормализации перешло в хранимую часть мантиссы. По идее, если мы выполняем обычное сложение, то целая часть мантиссы должна быть равна `1` (так как мы складываем значение `0` и `1`), но, очевидно, что логика здесь какая-то другая, так как конечный результат будет иметь совершенно другой порядок, и я просто что-то не так понимаю или не так учёл.

Ну и сама мантисса получилась немного другой после в конечном итоге, так как результат для мантиссы должен быть `11101101110100111011011`, а у меня получается `11101101110100111011000`. Не могу понять природы двух последних единиц, которые располагаются в младших битах мантиссы. Помогите найти ошибку, пожалуйста!

Ход моих действий следующий:

1. Представление двух вещественных чисел в формате `binary32`:

- -987.6543 — `1 10001000 11101101110100111100000`
- 1234.5678 — `0 10001001 00110100101001000101011`

2. порядок числа `-987.6543` (привожу его к порядку числа `1234.5678`), что влечёт за собой сдвиг внутри мантиссы. До изменения порядка мантисса была `1.11101101110100111100000`, а после изменения у нас произошёл сдвиг на `1` позицию вправо. Отсекаем лишний бит и получаем `0.11110110111010011110000`.
3. Представляю дробную часть мантиссы отрицательного числа в дополнительном коде: `0.00001001000101100010000`
4. Произвожу сложение дробных частей мантисс: `00110100101001000101011` + `00001001000101100010000` = `00111101101110100111011`. Если сложить целые части, то получается 1. Это один из моментов, который сбивает с толку. Целые части в данном случае не учитывается и если числа имеют разные знаки, то он всегда денормализован? Объясните этот момент, пожалуйста.

Но даже если я считаю результат денормализованым и совершаю сдвиги до тех пор, пока не получу нормализованную форму, я всё равно получаю в качестве конечного результата `11101101110100111011000`, так как освободившееся пространство заполняю нулями. Все калькуляторы указывают на то, что результатом для финальной мантиссы должно быть `11101101110100111011011`. По какому принципу добавили единицы? Это округление? Или что здесь происходит за кулисами? Что я не учёл?

Comment: Ваш вопрос довольно длинный, и поэтому на него никто не отвечает. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: "При изменении порядка числа -987.6543 самый младший бит был отсечён" - это ошибка. По стандарту числа складываются точно, затем сумма округляется. Если следуете стандарту, при выравнивании порядков биты не должны теряться. Это можно делать по-разному, но простое отсечение точно не работает.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Я изначально попытался так сделать, но получил совершенно иной результат, который кардинально отличается от ожидаемого. Расширил сетку на 1 бит и работал уже с 24-разрядной мантиссой. Не уверен, но мне кажется, что возможной проблемой является то, что один из операндов представляет собой отрицательное числовое значение, что обязывает нас перевести его бинарную форму в дополнительный доход (two`s complement).

Comment: докину сюда еще одну ссылку на калькулятор который отображает оба полученных варианта в сумме  https://mason.cc/float, так что на мой взгляд вероятно это не ошибка в расчете а более точное приближение

Comment: @Daniil Loban Да, но интересно то, что мантисса `11101101110100111011011` всё-таки ближе к истинному результату и имеет меньшую погрешность. Проблема лишь в том, что мне не понятна природа данного результата. Каким образом мы пришли к двум битам в самом конце, которые равны `11` мне так и непонятно. Когда произвожу обычные вычисления, то получаю иной результат.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы уверены насчёт **всех** калькуляторов? Пожалуйста, огласите весь список.

Я проверил ваши вычисления в Go, процессор Intel Core i7, ОС Windows 10: https://go.dev/play/p/XSHAXUF1843

Вот вывод программы:

```
x:       -987.6543 11000100011101101110100111100000 <sign: 1, 1.11101101110100111100000 * 2^(10001000-127)>
y:       1234.5677 01000100100110100101001000101011 <sign: 0, 1.00110100101001000101011 * 2^(10001001-127)>
x+y:     246.91345 01000011011101101110100111011000 <sign: 0, 1.11101101110100111011000 * 2^(10000110-127)>
```

Мнение Go (читай, аппаратуры x86_64) и ваши вычисления совпадают: мантисса (без ведущей единицы) равна `11101101110100111011000`

Того же мнения, кстати, придерживается калькулятор http://weitz.de/ieee/: бинарное значение суммы равно `0b01000011011101101110100111011000` - тоже никаких единиц
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кстати, обратите внимание, что 1234.5678 в двоичном представлении округляется до 1234.5677

**UPDATE**

По итогам экспериментов пришли к выводу, что некоторые калькуляторы делают вычисления с более выской точностью, и затем обрезают мантиссу.

Например, если складывать по правилам 32-х битных целых, мантисса суммы должна быть `11101101110100111011000`, но некоторые калькуляторы показали мантиссу `11101101110100111011011`. Такая мантисса получится, если вести вычисления в `binary64` или `binary128`, а затем обрезать мантиссу до 23-х бит.

Также ТС провёл эксперимент по вычислению суммы в `base64` и получил мантиссу `1110110111010011101101100100010110100001110010110000`, в то время как онлайн калькулятор выдал мантиссу `1110110111010011101101100100010110100001110010101100`. Причина расхождения та же: калькулятор вёл вычисления в `binary128`, а потом уменьшил разрядность до `binary64`.

**UPDATE 2**

Вспомнил про такой инструмент, как [GNU MPFR](https://www.mpfr.org/) - библиотека вещественных вычислений произвольной точности. Сама библиотека на Си, и непосредственно на Си ей пользоваться несколько неудобно, зато есть отличная обёртка для Python, `gmpy2`.

Сделал демонстрационный [блокнот Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VtFbApLdT6gfMTv96ZqZnhwroiu6ZcId?usp=sharing), который складывает числа из примера и выводит результат с различной точностью. Для вычислений использовалась точность 256 бит (размер мантиссы): слагаемые в десятичном представлении и соответствующие мантиссы

```
-987.6543000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004
 -1.111011011101001111000000000110100011011011100010111010110001110001000011001011001010010101111010011110000110110000100010011010000000100111010100100101010001100000101010100110010011000010111110000011011110110100
101000100011001110011100000011101011111011100

1234.5678
 1.001101001010010001010110110101011100111110101010110011011001111010000011111001000010010110101110111001100011000111111000101000001001000000101101111000000000110100011011011100010111010110001110001000011001011001010010101111010011110000110110000100010011010
```

Результат:

```
246.9134999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999994
 1.111011011101001110110110010001011010000111001010110000001000001100010010011011101001011110001101010011111101111100111011011001000101101000011100101011000000100000110001001001101110100101111000110101001111110111110011101101100100010110100001110010101100000
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144700/discussion-on-answer-by-pak-uula------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 3):

Попытаюсь расскрыть тему как я ее понимаю, анализ строил на основе [калькулятора](https://mason.cc/float), который собственно и дает результат с `11` на конце.

На мой взляд проблема не в сложении чисел точно. Так как я просто работал с конечным результатом `246.9135` (246.9135 = 246 + 0.9134999999999991 так части разбиваются в исходниках калькулятора, дробная получается путем вычета целой части, что влечет появление девяток, после 4х девяток анализ числа заканчивается, но это просто заметка)

Сам расчет мантисы дробной части в калькуляторе происходит справа в столбике (решил не переносить сюда). Там видно, что мы считаем только тысячные разряды  (`.913`) так что 5 которая теоретически становится 4-кой с 9-ми в периоде нас не интересует.

Мантиса у нас получается такой (результаты из столбика расчетов)

```
1110 1001 1101 1011 0010 00 (22 bit)
```

Тут я пометил те самые биты `11` которые считаю мы и обсуждаем.

Далее, у нас есть еще `Characteristic (Binary)` или запись целого числа `11110110` (8 bit)

Как я понимаю происходит их стыковка, точнее первые 16 бит дробной мантисы Мантисы

`1110100111011011`001000 добавляюся после `1.1110110` те же 8 бит записанные как дробь. И мы получаем научную нотацию:

1.11101101110100111011011×2<sup>7</sup>

Которая визуально соответствует `IEEE-754` за исключением точки и ведущей единицы которая отбрасывается за своей очевидностью:

`11101101110100111011011` Из чего я делаю вывод, что они имеют общую природу.

Что касается экспоненты, то, насколько я понимаю она высчитывается так:

```
   0111111 
 +     111 
  10000110 = Exponent
```

Добавляем 7 так как 2<sup>7</sup> в научной нотации

Число знака или `Sign Bit` = 0, так как наше число положительное (при отрицательном 1)

И таким образом, у меня не возникает противоречий и сомнений в подсчетах, но возможно я что-то упустил.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Действительно, похоже на то, что Вы верно докопались до природы происхождения младших битов мантиссы на примере конкретного калькулятора. Вопрос оказался достаточно интересным, так как в каждом калькуляторе присутствует свой алгоритм округления, который ведёт к более или менее точному результату. Над этой темой я лично поразмыслил и пришёл к интересному решению, которое также хочу вынести на общее обсуждение в виде отдельного ответа.

Answer (score 3):

Большое спасибо всем, кто подбросил правильные мысли и направил в нужное русло! Готов констатировать, что правильных ответов оказалось фактически несколько, так как во всех суждениях было рациональное зерно.

Теперь хотелось бы перейти к самой сути вопроса. Действительно, было интересно наблюдать за тем, как различные калькуляторы не могут прийти к единому результату одной и той же арифметической операции и предлагают минимум 2 альтернативных решения. Я не могу сказать, что какие-то программы допускают ошибку в вычислительном процессе, но если мы хотим прийти к максимально точному результату (пусть даже приближённому), то необходимо действовать через расширение двоичной разрядной сетки в ходе вычислений.

Немного тезисов о том, в каких случаях могут возникнуть проблемы с точностью конечного результата:

- Проблема точного представления непосредственных операндов. Сталкиваемся с этим достаточно часто, когда дробную часть исходного числа невозможно точно представить в виде двоичной дроби (проблема точного перевода числа из десятичной системы счисления в двоичную). Уже на этом этапе мы столкнёмся с первичной погрешностью, которую невозможно никоим образом избежать (её можно лишь уменьшить при смене формата представления вещественных чисел на более расширенный), но осознание неизбежности неминуемо приведёт к принятию.
- Проблема потенциальной потери значащих битов при приведении порядков и нормализации итогового результата. Именно это и стало ключевым в нашем вопросе.

Да, стоит признать, что обычное представление некоторого вещественного числа по канонам стандарта `IEEE754` и произведение между 2 числами любой арифметической операции — это далеко не одно и то же! Сам стандарт крайне рекомендует прийти к выбору правильной стратегии округления, если мы хотим достичь максимальной точности. Она не всегда нужна, поэтому погрешности тоже имеют место и это вполне нормально. Тем не менее, в нашем примере мы имеем место с операндами, которые имеют по модулю *разные порядки*. Но ещё более критичным моментом является не это, а то, что порядок итогового результата отличался от порядка приведённых операндов на 3 значения.

Вспомним наш базовый алгоритм, чтобы немного прояснить ситуацию. Если порядки операндов изначально отличаются, то мы всегда ориентируемся на порядок большего по модулю операнда. Именно меньший операнд мы всегда будем приводить к большему. Так делать действительно удобнее и целесообразнее. Именно в рамках большего порядка мы и производим сложение мантисс (не забываем и о сдвиге, который происходит внутри мантиссы в процессе повышения порядка), а затем уже смотрим на результат операции и в случае необходимости реализуем нормализацию.

Моё предложение заключается в том, чтобы на начальном этапе высчитать разницу между порядком *бóльшего* операнда и порядком *результирующего* числа. Как уже писалось чуть выше, мы сдвинули мантиссу на 3 шага влево, чтобы прийти к нормализованной форме. Но что критичного для точности произошло в результате этого сдвига? Мы получили 3 незаполненных младших бита мантиссы, места которых освободились и должны быть чем-то заполнены. С потолка мы придумывать значения не будем, поэтому и заполняем их нулями. Вот здесь всё и скрывалось...

Я решил эту проблему путём компенсирующего расширения мантиссы на 3 разряда, которые у нас освобождаются в ходе нормализации результата. Изначально представил исходные числа так, будто бы хранимая часть мантиссы имеет длину не 23 бита (для `binary32`), а 26 бит.

Мантиссы получились следующие:

- 1234.5678 — `00110100101001000101011011`
- -987.6543 — `11101101110100111100000000`

Таким образом, все вычисления производились уже внутри 26-разрядной битовой сетки, а не 23-разрядной, как изначально.

Выравниваю порядок числа -987.6543 с числом 1234.5678 (увеличиваю порядок операнда -987.6543 на `1` значение): `11110110111010011110000000`. Здесь у нас значение бита нормализации перешло в дробную (хранимую) часть мантиссы, а младший бит мы отсекли, так как в результате сдвига он не помещается в нашу расширенную разрядную сетку.

Перевожу значение отрицательного числа в дополнительный код: `00001001000101100010000000`. А затем просто складываю мантиссы в рамках единого порядка: `00110100101001000101011011` + `00001001000101100010000000` = `00111101101110100111011011`.
Приводим число к нормализованному виду через понижение порядка (сдвигаем мантиссу до тех пор, пока разряд со значением `1` не встанет на место неявного бита нормализации). Для этого мы и сдвигаем мантиссу на 3 шага влево. Получаем итоговую мантиссу `1.11101101110100111011011`, где `11101101110100111011011` будет храниться явно. Да, у нас снова освободилось 3 разряда в хвосте нашего числа, но эти разряды нам уже совершенно неинтересны, так как результат мы будем записывать в 23-разрядную мантиссу формата `binary32`.

Итак, вывод! Если мы хотим получить наиболее точный результат, то все вычисления необходимо проводить в расширенной разрядной сетке, величина которой будет больше фиксированного размера для выбранного формата представления на количественную разницу между порядком большего операнда и порядком результирующего числа (благодарю
*Stanislav Volodarskiy* за наводку). Но ещё больше мне нравится мысль (и скорее всего так и работает большая часть калькуляторов) о том, что если нам нужен максимально точный результат для заданного формата, то нам проще проводить вычисления в более расширенном формате, а результат записывать (ту часть, которая поместится) уже в целевом формате. Единственная проблема заключается в том, что если мы захотим представить результат с наименьшей погрешностью в `binary128` или `binary256`, то проще будет воспользоваться расширением разрядной сетки на необходимое количество бит, так как есть риск дойти до предела. На эту мысль меня подтолкнул уважаемый *Pak Uula*, за что ему очень сильно благодарен!

Буду рад любым комментариям и замечаниям!